# mui table is not responsive

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I am using mui [table](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#data-table). It is not responsive. I need to set the width in %.

The output is
I attach the screenshort from two different screen

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post your code if you want a real answer. You should let MUI handle the width, just add styling props to your Table: `<Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }}>`.

Answer (score 12):

Create a div container with `overflow: auto`, then another container

with: `width: '100%', display: 'table', tableLayout: 'fixed'`

And that's all.

```html
 <div className="App">
      <Box sx={{ overflow: "auto" }}>
        <Box sx={{ width: "100%", display: "table", tableLayout: "fixed" }}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                  <TableSortLabel>Name</TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <TableSortLabel>User</TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <TableSortLabel>Title</TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <TableSortLabel>Role</TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align={"right"}></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow hover>
                <TableCell>
                  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Avatar
                      sx={{
                        height: 42,
                        width: 42,
                        backgroundColor: "primary.main"
                      }}
                    >
                      MD
                    </Avatar>
                    <Box sx={{ ml: 1 }}>
                      <Link
                        color={"inherit"}
                        variant={"subtitle2"}
                        component={"a"}
                        sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                      >
                        Darwling Jackson
                      </Link>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>DJackson</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Tester</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Editor</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow hover>
                <TableCell>
                  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Avatar
                      sx={{
                        height: 42,
                        width: 42,
                        backgroundColor: "primary.main"
                      }}
                    >
                      MD
                    </Avatar>
                    <Box sx={{ ml: 1 }}>
                      <Link
                        color={"inherit"}
                        variant={"subtitle2"}
                        sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                      >
                        Jhon Phoneix
                      </Link>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>JP</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Database Administrator</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Editor</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow hover>
                <TableCell>
                  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <Avatar
                      sx={{
                        height: 42,
                        width: 42,
                        backgroundColor: "primary.main"
                      }}
                    >
                      MD
                    </Avatar>
                    <Box sx={{ ml: 1 }}>
                      <Link
                        color={"inherit"}
                        variant={"subtitle2"}
                        sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                      >
                        Maria Dominguez
                      </Link>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>MDominguez</TableCell>
                <TableCell>IT Manager</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Editor</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
```

See my example: [Mui responsive code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-rain-3jyice?file=/src/App.js:182-3999)

Comment: You're a damn genius.  I have had this problem for months on multiple tables.  Thank you!!

Comment: this worked for me, thank you. However I though that MUI should get it done just using the `TableContainer` component, shouldn't ?

Comment: It's strange but for me this recipe doesn't work

Comment: click on the sandbox @DmitryMalugin

Answer (score 0):

Can't really demonstrate without code, but if you don't want to let Material UI to determine the width, a common strategy is to wrap the component in a `Box`, and give the width (in percent) to the Box instead. [Reference](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/#main-content).

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove `min-width` from `<th>` & `<td>`:

```
    .css-1wjk1gj-MuiTable-root {
        min-width: unset !important
    }
```

Comment: There are sometimes when you can customize the element by CSS, this is not the case since the root class of a `Table` component is `MuiTable-root` not the one that you are providing.